# I have tried to copy URL which is opened in new tab but copying old tab urls. How to copy new tab url java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

How to copy new tab url java selenium?

```
'package TestCases;

public class Learn_TC3 extends SuperTestScript
{
    @Test
    public void  LoginTC1() throws Exception
    {
        //all the required data
        
                String USRID = ExcelLibrary.readData("Sheet1", 0, 0);
                String PSW = ExcelLibrary.readData("Sheet1", 0, 1);
                
                
        //create page objects
                LearnPage Lp = new LearnPage();
                Tabswitch Ts = new Tabswitch();
                
        //invoke the methods
                Lp.ClickonMaterialsButton();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Lp.ClickonPDF1();//By clicking on pdf. Pdf opens in new tab
                String CurrentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();// to Fetch new url
                ExcelLibrary.writeData("Sheet1", 0, 4, CurrentUrl);//write url to excel sheet?
                Ts.switchToPreviousTabAndClose();   //Closing new tab
    }
}'
```

I have tried to copy URL which is opened in new tab but copying old tab urls. How to copy new tab url java selenium?

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on `Lp.ClickonPDF1()` that opens a new tab you have to switch Selenium driver to the opened tab in order to perform actions there.
So your code can be something like this:

```java
Lp.ClickonMaterialsButton();
Thread.sleep(3000);
Lp.ClickonPDF1();//By clicking on pdf. Pdf opens in new tab

Thread.sleep(500);
List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size()-1));

String CurrentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();// to Fetch new url
ExcelLibrary.writeData("Sheet1", 0, 4, CurrentUrl);//write url to excel sheet?
Ts.switchToPreviousTabAndClose();   //Closing new tab
```

Not sure how can I use the `driver` object in your infrastructure, so I used it as regular, with no relation to any page object instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that pretty easily with `Selenium 4`

**Code**:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
driver.navigate().to("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

**Output**:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
```

You can do like below with your code,

```
Lp.ClickonPDF1();
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
String CurrentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are methods that I created for a test project (using cucumber-java and selenium-java) that is similar to your approach, where it was required to:

1. Click on a link for a pdf document on a webpage, which opened in a new tab
2. List the opened tabs
3. Move to the new tab
4. Get the url for the pdf document and verify (assert) that it was correct
5. Close the pdf tab
6. Return to the webpage

Feel free to use what you need

```
    @Then("^on \"([^\"]*)\" I can view the Pdf Document of \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void on_I_can_view_the_Pdf_Document_of(String relativeUrl, String document) throws Throwable {
        viewPDFDocument(relativeUrl, document);
    }

    private void viewPdfDocument(String relativeUrl, String document) throws Exception {
        clickOnLink("", document);
        verifyPdfUrl();
    }

    public void clickOnLink(String linkXpath, String label) throws Exception {

        LOG.info("Clicking link '{}' with xpath '{}'", label, linkXpath);

        retryIfAssertionFails(() -> {
            String xpath = linkXpath + "//a/descendant-or-self::*[contains(normalize-space(text()), '" + label + "')]";
            waitForElementToBeClickable(xpath);
            driver.findElementByXPath(xpath).click();
            return null;
        });

        LOG.info("Link clicked");
        sleep(50);

    }

    private void verifyPdfUrl() throws Exception {
        String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

        for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandle)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
            }
        }

        String pdfTabUrl;
        pdfTabUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        assertTrue(pdfTabUrl.contains(
                "/app/restrict/application/caseInformation.pdf")); {
            System.out.println("Correct url presented: " + pdfTabUrl);
        }

        if (!driver.getWindowHandle().equals(parentWindowHandle)) {
            driver.close();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);
    }
```

In your case it is updating to the following:

```
                Lp.ClickonMaterialsButton();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Lp.ClickonPDF1();//By clicking on pdf. Pdf opens in new tab
                String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

                for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                  if (!windowHandle.equals(parentWindowHandle)) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                  }
                }

               String pdfTabUrl;
               pdfTabUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();  // to Fetch new url
               ExcelLibrary.writeData("Sheet1", 0, 4, pdfTabUrl);   //write url to excel sheet?
               if (!driver.getWindowHandle().equals(parentWindowHandle)) {
                 driver.close();
               }   //Closing new tab
               driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);   //Switch back to original tab
```